# Error in jquery : objected expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have following jquery code but in IE it is showing "Object expected" error at first line.I tried debugging it but i cant find any bug.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("file1.json", function (data) {
            $.each(data.firstName, function (i, s) {
                alert(s);
            });
        }).error(function (jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
            alert("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is jQuery loaded?

Comment: Runs perfectly in IE 7-9. Fiddle http://jsbin.com/epavaz/1/edit

Comment: possibly need to set a header for IE to treat it as JSON?

Comment: Thanks all possibly i was referring obsolete path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if jQuery has been added before you run this code. If so, try wrapping your code in an anonymous function:

**html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
;(function($) {
// your jQuery code:
$(document).ready(function() {...});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: 2nd part is unnecessary. `$(document).ready` is enough. Plus, v1.9.1 is advised to use with jQuery Migrate plugin, as stated in official documentation.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor 2nd one will cover any conflict possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below things

1. Check the jquery javascript file referred
2. Check for the correct order, if you have a dependency ( For example, jquery.js first and dependent file like UI or yourJSFile is next)
3. Make sure this function executes after the script file loaded, that is the `$` or `jQuery` object was constructed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i suggest ,can you replace

```
$.getJSON("file1.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data.firstName, function (i, s) {
            alert(s);
        });
```

with this

```
$.getJSON("file1.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data.firstName, function (name) {
            alert(name);
        });
```

Comment: `remove ';' from the last line` ??? Not true.  Depending on the browser and the way the code is structured it may not be strictly required, but it always makes sense to terminate a line of code with `;`